# Vectors of pointers to other vector's elements

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

EI have function which takes as parameter pointer to vector:

```
void Function(std::vector<type>* aa)
```

Now inside this function I want to filter out data from that vector to another vector and I want to change data of original vector by changing values of this temporary one. Damn it's hard to understand something like:

```
void Function(std::vector<type>* aa)
{
    std::vector<type*> temp; //to this vector I filter out data and by changning 
    //values of this vector I want to autmatically change values of aa vector
}
```

I have something like that:

```
void Announce_Event(std::vector<Event>& foo)
{
    std::vector<Event> current;
    tm current_time = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    time_t thetime;
    thetime = time(NULL);
    localtime_s(&current_time, &thetime);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < foo.size(); ++i) {
        if (foo[i].day == current_time.tm_mday &&
            foo[i].month == current_time.tm_mon &&
            foo[i].year == current_time.tm_year+1900)
        {
            current.push_back(foo[i]);
        }
    }
    std::cout << current.size() << std::endl;
    current[0].title = "Changed"; //<-- this is suppose to change value.
}
```

That does not change original value.

Comment: Why a pointer? Why not a reference? And it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Question is how can I achieve it?

Comment: You seem to want to do two things. Can you do either one? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to do one thing. I want to know how can I change values of aa vector by changing data in temp, shouldn't I use pointers which will point to elements of aa vector? I am trying all the time but I'm getting compilator errors.

Comment: Why don't you just fill temp vector and then swap it with aa? And yes, in your code your vectors are different `vector<type>` and `vector<type*>`

Comment: @adadad: the posted could should technically compile.  Post a sample attempt and associated compiler errors.  This will likely help us help you!

Comment: Please give a more concrete example of what you'd like to do. Even with pseudocode that won't actually do it. Your description is vague and the currently voted highest answer is somewhat non-sensical. If you do this, you will likely clarify things for yourself too and the answer to your problem might become clear.

Answer (score 6):

I think you may be having trouble communicating your intentions, so this calls for a psychic answer.

```
void Func(std::vector<type> & aa)
{
    std::vector<type*> temp;

    // I wish <algorithm> had a 'transform_if'    
    for(int i=0; i<aa.size(); ++i)
    {
        if( some_test(aa[i]) )
            temp.push_back(&aa[i])
    }

    // This leaves temp with pointers to some of the elements of aa.
    // Only those elements which passed some_test().  Now any modifications
    // to the dereferenced pointers in temp will modify those elements
    // of aa.  However, keep in mind that if elements are added or
    // removed from aa, it may invalidate the pointers in temp.
}
```

Comment: If you want to be sure that the pointers aren't invalidated, use a `std::deque` for your main container. If the elements are added at the beginning or the end, the pointers are still valid.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a pointer to a `vector`, use a reference instead:

```
void Function(std::vector<type>& aa)
```

inside the function you can now access the vectors contents as usual.

```
void Function(std::vector<type>& aa)
{
    std::vector<type>& temp = aa;

    // if you now append something to temp, it is also appended to aa
    aa.push_back(type());
}
```

I don't know why you want two references to one vector, but hey, you asked :)

EDIT: removed typo, see comments. thanx

Comment: I have somthing like:  'code'void Oglos_Wydarzenie(std::vector<Wydarzenie>& zmienna)
{
 std::vector<Wydarzenie> obecne;
 tm AktualnyCzas = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
 time_t czas;
 czas = time(NULL);
 localtime_s(&AktualnyCzas,&czas);
 for (unsigned i = 0; i < zmienna.size(); ++i)
 if (zmienna[i].dzien == AktualnyCzas.tm_mday && zmienna[i].miesiac == AktualnyCzas.tm_mon && zmienna[i].rok == AktualnyCzas.tm_year+1900)
  obecne.push_back(zmienna[i]);
 std::cout << obecne.size() << std::endl;
 obecne[0].tytul = "Zmienione";
}'code'  and it does not change original value

Comment: @adadad: Edit that into your question.

Comment: @adadad It's a good idea to write code in English, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I translated the example to English. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, start formatting your code better. Messy code is difficult to understand and makes it harder for you to figure out what you're trying to do.

This will do what you want:

```
void Oglos_Wydarzenie(std::vector<Wydarzenie>& zmienna)
{
    std::vector<Wydarzenie *> obecne;
    tm AktualnyCzas = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    time_t czas;
    czas = time(NULL);
    localtime_s(&AktualnyCzas,&czas);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < zmienna.size(); ++i) {
        if (zmienna[i].dzien == AktualnyCzas.tm_mday &&
            zmienna[i].miesiac ==  AktualnyCzas.tm_mon &&
            zmienna[i].rok == AktualnyCzas.tm_year+1900)
        {
            obecne.push_back(&zmienna[i]);
        }
    }
    std::cout << obecne.size() << std::endl;
    obecne[0]->tytul = "Changed"; //<-- this is suppose to change value.
}
```

You could do this with all pointers and no references at all, but then it looks much more confusing:

```
void Oglos_Wydarzenie(std::vector<Wydarzenie>* zmienna)
{
    std::vector<Wydarzenie *> obecne;
    tm AktualnyCzas = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    time_t czas;
    czas = time(NULL);
    localtime_s(&AktualnyCzas,&czas);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < zmienna->size(); ++i) {
        if ((*zmienna)[i].dzien == AktualnyCzas.tm_mday &&
            (*zmienna)[i].miesiac ==  AktualnyCzas.tm_mon &&
            (*zmienna)[i].rok == AktualnyCzas.tm_year+1900)
        {
            obecne.push_back(&((*zmienna)[i]));
        }
    }
    std::cout << obecne.size() << std::endl;
    obecne[0]->tytul = "Changed"; //<-- this is suppose to change value.
}
```